# How To Setup Core Data Model For Simple App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data

I'm familiar with core data but want to make a simple app that calculates salary.
User enters their expenses, etc and it will determine how much their income needs to be to make it work.

I'm thinking I make an entity for each `Event` and then have an attribute `expense` for each expense.

Is there then an easy way to add all these values of `expense` properties and do some calculations with them?  I will set their type to float or nsnumber or int, etc.

Update: I will make the relationship of Event to Expense to many and the inverse relation ship would be one to one. But about actually doing calculations with these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to add many values to Entity, you must use a relationship between them, it's the only way to have and Event with its Expenses...

Event <---->> Expense

An Event has too many Expenses and every Expense belongs to an Event...

Comment: Yes, I will make the relationship of Event to Expense `to many` and the inverse relation ship would be `one to one`.  But about actually doing calculations with these values?

Comment: you would need to add a selector on the Event entity which allows you to make calculations about their NSSet of Expenses, that is ...      - (CGFloat)costCalculation {
    CGFloat calc = 0.0;
    
    for (Expense *exp in self.expenses)
        calc += exp.value;
    
    return calc;
}

Comment: Thanks, how exactly do i add the selector to an `Event`?  I know how to add that method you put.

Comment: You need to generate the Class for the Event entity from your data model and add a selector exactly like another Class...

Comment: So in the data model, I have to change the class for `Event` to `Event` instead of `NSManagedObject`, right?  And what is the line of code to add a selector?

Comment: File > New... > New File > Core Data & NSManagedObject subclass > Next > select data model... > Select Entity and create. Now you have a Event subclass from NSManagebObject, here is where you can define a selector for all your Events...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I have the subclass file already, I just need do add the actual selector to it, which I haven't done before.